# Regex to match a username

Tags: html, regex, validation

I am trying to create a regex to validate usernames which should match the following :

- Only one special char `(._-)` allowed and it must not be at the extremes of the string
- The first character cannot be a number
- All the other characters allowed are letters and numbers
- The total length should be between 3 and 20 chars

This is for an HTML validation pattern, so sadly it must be one big regex.

So far this is what I've got:

```
^(?=(?![0-9])[A-Za-z0-9]+[._-]?[A-Za-z0-9]+).{3,20}
```

But the positive lookahead can be repeated more than one time allowing to be more than one special character which is not what I wanted. And I don't know how to correct that.

Comment: Not an answer yet - but you need to break `.` in `[._-]`.

Comment: For something this complicated, why are you choosing to go with an html validation pattern?  You could trigger an event that handles the validation rather than the pattern.

Comment: @amit [._-] is a single character in the list "._-" literally so the dot isn't considered any character, so I think I don't need to break it

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should split your regex into two parts (not two Expressions!) to make your life easier:

First, match the format the username needs to have:
`^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*[._-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+$`

Now, we just need to validate the length constraint. In order to not mess around with the already found pattern, you can use a non-consuming match that only validates the number of characters (its literally a hack for creating an *and* pattern for your regular expression): `(?=^.{3,20}$)`

The regex will only try to match the valid *format* if the length constraint is matched. It is non-consuming, so after it is successful, the engine still is at the start of the string.

so, all together:

```
 (?=^.{3,20}$)^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*[._-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debugger Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/KevLpqQcKIbeuB3N)

Comment: Thank you master of the regex, this works (I just had to replace the last * by a + so a special char can't be at the end

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `?` instead of `+`, so the special character is matched only once or not.

`^(?=(?![0-9])?[A-Za-z0-9]?[._-]?[A-Za-z0-9]+).{3,20}`

Comment: That would only allow a special character to be on the start of the string

Comment: @Adri1du40 Are you sure? I think `?` is basically `+` except it's only matched zero times or once.

Comment: Yes, this is what '?' does but if you let a character to be zero times before the special char, then a special char can be at the start

Comment: Ah, okay. That's right. Anyway, you already have an accepted answer.