# Regex for password policy with trim function

Tags: regex, trim, password-policy

I need to create a regex for a password policy.

- The password has to contain at least 6 characters.
- The password has to contain at least one lowercase letter.
- The password has to contain at least one upercase letter.
- The password has to contain at least one special character.
- Whitespaces in the middle of the password are allowed, but not at the beginning and at the end (=> trim function).

My interim result is this expression:

> ^(?=.* [A-Z])(?=.* [a-z])(?=.*\W).{6,}$

It works for the first four criterions, but not for the trim function.

I tried something linke this:

> (?=\S[\s]* )(?=.* [A-Z])(?=.* [a-z])(?=.* \W).{6,}$

but this doesn't work, because whitespaces at the end are still possible.

Could anyone help me to extend my result, so that the regex allows whitespaces in the middle of the password, but not at the beginning and not at the end?

Comment: From your first try:  `^(?=.* [A-Z])(?=.* [a-z])(?=.*\W).{6,}$`
with "no space at beginning"  
`^[^\s](?=.* [A-Z])(?=.* [a-z])(?=.*\W).{6,}$`. Add password examples regexp should match or not match to validate

Comment: Why do you need to create "a regex" for that? Why not multiple regexes? Using a list of regexes would simply this code a lot. What language/tool/library are you using?

Comment: Hey, you're right! It is not necessary to implement the policy with one regex. I thought there's something linke a default Implementation for a problem like this. I am using java. Do your have an idea, how to solve this case with a list of regexes?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with Java. But e.g. in Perl you could do something like `if ( length($str) >= 6 && $str =~ /[[:upper:]]/ && $str =~ /[[:lower:]]/ && $str =~ /[^[:alnum:]]/ && $str !~ /\A\s/ && $str !~ /\s\z/ )`.

Comment: You actually may do it with a regex like `s.matches("(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=\\w*\\W)\\S.{5,}\\z(?<!\\s)")`. If you need to account for a `_` as a special char, replace `(?=\\w*\\W)` with `(?=[\\w&&[^_]]*[\\W_])`

Comment: It works! Thank your very much, you saved may day! :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex to match a username](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28392975/regex-to-match-a-username)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28392975/regex-to-match-a-username/28393106#28393106 - The same logic can be applied to passwords instead of usernames.